# ¿Cómo agregar privilegio Super a mi usuario de MySQL? en PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, eventos

En mí base de datos creé un evento que funciona, está en "Enabled", pero no puedo iniciarlo porque necesito privilegios `SUPER` en `PhpMyAdmin`.

En la sección de `Eventos` esta la siguiente opción:

> Estado del planificador de eventos: Apagado

*Esta es una captura de pantalla:*

[image: Estado del planificador de eventos: Apagado]

---

Intento cambiarlo para encenderlo y esto es lo siguiente:

*Captura de pantalla: Acceso denegado*

[image: Access Denied]

> consulta SQL:
>   **SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  "ON"** MySQL ha dicho: Documentación 1227 - **Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation**

No encuentro la opción de editar los permisos de usuarios. ¿Es posible que tenga que comunicarme con el soporte del host del server para tener este privilegio Super?

La base de datos esta en un servidor, no en mi pc local.

La versión de PHPMyAdmin es: **4.0.10.18**

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de servidor, Hosting, VPS, Cloud.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora se a que se debe el problema,

como mencione antes el server no esta alojado localmente en mi PC, es un servidor pago, de Wiroos,  por lo que no tengo el control total. 
Resulta que al ser un plan normal de "entorno compartido", (lo que significa que en el servidor físico donde se hostean mis bases de datos etc) tiene los recursos de hardware compartidos con otros usuarios. La limitación se debe a que al ejecutar scripts, eventos etc, pueden consumir estos recursos compartidos con la posibilidad de traer problemas a los demas, por esta razón lo inhabilitan.

Para que puedan darme Super usuario, tengo que tener un servidor DEDICADO para mi solo (mucho mas caro) de esta manera si podría usar todos los recursos que necesite y que tenga asignado en mi servidor dedicado.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta conectarte desde la consola a MySQL y ejecuta lo siguiente

```
mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO usuario@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Para hacerlo desde phpMyAdmin debes ir a

```
cuentas de usuario > seleccionar usuario > editar privilegios
```

Ahi encontraras la opcion `SUPER` o si quieres puedes marcar toda la sección llamada `Administracion`

Con eso le daras SUPER privilegios a tu usuario en MySQL

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, mi problema esta en que esa opcion de usuarios no la tengo, (lo vi en videos). 
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/p48BD3c.jpg

No tengo idea de como seguir, el comando de consola lo ejecute y tengo lo siguiente
**Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'servici3_reserva'@'190.55.xx.xxx' (using password: YES)**

Use el unico usuario que esta asignado a esa base de datos

Comment: debes buscar la opción que se llame cuentas de usuario, a mi me sale al lado de la opción `Estado Actual` fijate al final si tienes una opcion que se llama `mas` puede que ahí este

Comment: Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que intentes hacerlo con otro usuario por ejemplo puedes probar con el usuario `root` si no tienes las credenciales intenta hacer [esto](http://ecapy.com/como-recuperar-la-clave-root-en-mysql-solucion-a-veces-pasa-d/)

Comment: Mil gracias! cuando vuelva de la facu pruebo y comento. gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me funcionó:

En el home de phpMyAdmin hay varias cajas con información, en 'Servidor de base de datos' busca 'Usuario'

y luego lo remplazas en el archivo sql.

entonces todos los renglones deberían cambiar de esto:

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`antiguo_user`@`localhost`*/
```

a esto:

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`usuario_phpMyAdmin`@`localhost`*/
```

y ahí ya te debe dejar importar la base de datos.